# Having multiple text files open

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, text-files

I am having trouble with a program involving three text files and processing them. The kicker for me is getting the files to open. Am I missing something? I have previously tried four variables but that yielded the same result. I am getting "Error! {file.txt} File not found", so my exception is working. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
def main():
    process_file("good_data.txt")
    process_file("bad_data.txt")
    process_file("empty_file.txt")
    process_file("does_not_exist.txt")

def process_file(param_str_file_name):

  #Variables
  num_rec = 0
  total = 0
  average = 0

  try:
      file_name = open('param_str_file_name', 'r')


      print("Processing file", file_name)


      variable = file_name.readline()

      while variable != "":
        file_name_int = int(file_name)
        num_rec = num_rec + 1

        variable = file_name.readline()

        total += file_name_int
        average = total / num_rec

      file_name.close()


      print("\tRecord count = ", num_rec)
      print("\tTotal        = ", total)
      print("\tAverage      = " , f"{average:.2f}", "\n")

  except EOFError:
    print("\tError!", param_str_file_name, " is empty. Cannot calculate average\n")

  except FileNotFoundError:
      print("\tError!", param_str_file_name, " File not found\n")

  except ValueError:
      print("\tError!", param_str_file_name, "contains non-numeric data\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The files have to be in the same folder as your Python program, but other than that I don't see any problems with the code